# Centrar la vista en una palabra que haya buscado en un textbox

Tags: c#

Tengo 2 textbox, en uno cargo y muestro un texto y en el otro introduzco una palabra, la busco y la resalto en el texto. Los textos son muy largos y no entra todo, por lo que parte del texto no aparece(uso un scrollbar). Quiero saber es si hay alguna manera de que si la palabra no esta en las primeras lineas visibles vaya automáticamente a donde esté la palabra buscada.
Uso esto para buscar y resaltar:

```
      public void ResaltarTexto(TextBox txtBx, string texto) 
     {
        int posición = txtBx.Text.IndexOf(texto);                  
        txtBx.Focus();
        txtBx.SelectionStart = posición;
        txtBx.SelectionLength = texto.Length;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buenas Xavier,

Puedes usar la propiedad de `TextBox` [`ScrollToCaret();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret(v=vs.110).aspx) que hace Scroll para mostrarte dónde tienes el símbolo de intercalación (selección):

```
 public void ResaltarTexto(TextBox txtBx, string texto) 
 {
    int posición = txtBx.Text.IndexOf(texto);                  
    txtBx.Focus();
    txtBx.SelectionStart = posición;
    txtBx.SelectionLength = texto.Length;
    txtBx.ScrollToCaret();
}
```